# Exe created with py2exe doesn't work and returns logfile with errors

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, py2exe, logfile-analysis

It's my first post so go easy on me. My problem is similar as in here, but I couldn't make it work, though I really tried:
" [py2exe with enthought and pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18869421/py2exe-with-enthought-and-pandas) ".

Having installed separately both versions of python(x84-64, x32) with libraries I proceeded to making an executable of python script using py2exe. 
I had to download missing dll files: msvcp90.dll, libiomp5md.dll, libifcoremd.dll, libmmd.dll.
Exe files I created return errors and a logfile is generated - different for x32 and x64 python&libraries.

For 32 bit python&libraries I got the following logfiles(different depending on which numpy library I installed from: http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#numpy)

For numpy-1.8.0-win32-superpack-python2.7 I received multipled following information:

```
File "gui.py", line 7, in <module>
File "pyqtgraph\__init__.pyc", line 177, in <module>
File "pyqtgraph\__init__.pyc", line 167, in importAll
File "pyqtgraph\__init__.pyc", line 159, in importModules
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "gua.py", line 7, in <module>
File "pyqtgraph\__init__.pyc", line 180, in <module>
File "pyqtgraph\imageview\__init__.pyc", line 6, in <module>
File "pyqtgraph\imageview\ImageView.pyc", line 20, in <module>
File "pyqtgraph\imageview\ImageViewTemplate_pyqt.pyc", line 159, in <module>
File "pyqtgraph\widgets\PlotWidget.pyc", line 10, in <module>
File "pyqtgraph\graphicsItems\PlotItem\__init__.pyc", line 1, in <module>
File "pyqtgraph\graphicsItems\PlotItem\PlotItem.pyc", line 32, in <module>
File "pyqtgraph\graphicsItems\PlotDataItem.pyc", line 4, in <module>
File "pyqtgraph\graphicsItems\PlotCurveItem.pyc", line 4, in <module>
File "scipy\stats\__init__.pyc", line 324, in <module>
File "scipy\stats\stats.pyc", line 242, in <module>
File "scipy\special\__init__.pyc", line 531, in <module>
File "scipy\special\_ufuncs.pyc", line 12, in <module>
File "scipy\special\_ufuncs.pyc", line 10, in __load
File "_ufuncs.pyx", line 1, in init scipy.special._ufuncs (scipy\special\_ufuncs.c:19840)
ImportError: No module named _ufuncs_cxx
```

For numpy-MKL- 1.8.0.win32-py 2.7:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "gui.py", line 2, in <module>
File "numpy\__init__.pyc", line 154, in <module>
File "numpy\add_newdocs.pyc", line 9, in <module>
File "numpy\lib\__init__.pyc", line 13, in <module>
File "numpy\lib\polynomial.pyc", line 17, in <module>
File "numpy\linalg\__init__.pyc", line 48, in <module>
File "numpy\linalg\linalg.pyc", line 23, in <module>
File "numpy\linalg\lapack_lite.pyc", line 12, in <module>
File "numpy\linalg\lapack_lite.pyc", line 10, in __load
ImportError: DLL load failed: %1 is not a valid Win32 application.
```

For numpy-MKL-1.7.2rc1.win32-py2.7 I received as above, but multiplied.

For 64 bit python&libraries I got the following, irrelatively of scipy and numpy version:

```
File "gui.py", line 7, in <module>
File "pyqtgraph\__init__.pyc", line 177, in <module>
File "pyqtgraph\__init__.pyc", line 167, in importAll
File "pyqtgraph\__init__.pyc", line 159, in importModules
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "pyqtgraph\__init__.pyc", line 155, in importModules
File "pyqtgraph\graphicsItems\PlotDataItem.pyc", line 4, in <module>
File "pyqtgraph\graphicsItems\PlotCurveItem.pyc", line 4, in <module>
File "scipy\stats\__init__.pyc", line 324, in <module>
File "scipy\stats\stats.pyc", line 242, in <module>
File "scipy\special\__init__.pyc", line 531, in <module>
File "scipy\special\_ufuncs.pyc", line 12, in <module>
File "scipy\special\_ufuncs.pyc", line 10, in __load
File "_ufuncs.pyx", line 1, in init scipy.special._ufuncs (scipy\special\_ufuncs.c:19992)
ImportError: No module named _ufuncs_cxx
```

I do have some ufuncs files in ..\build\bdist.win-amd64\winexe\collect-2.7\scipy\special , but I'm not sure how it works or should work.

So what do I do to make any of these .exe work? Preferably, the one that goes with 64-bit python, because opening the program by running the code in SciTe with 32-bit python took ages and there was a memory overload.

***EDIT:***

After removing  `import numpy, pyqtgraph, scipy` from setup.py I get the following logfile with errors:

```
File "gui.py", line 7, in <module>
File "pyqtgraph\__init__.pyc", line 177, in <module>
File "pyqtgraph\__init__.pyc", line 167, in importAll
File "pyqtgraph\__init__.pyc", line 159, in importModules
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "pyqtgraph\__init__.pyc", line 155, in importModules
File "pyqtgraph\graphicsItems\PlotDataItem.pyc", line 4, in <module>
File "pyqtgraph\graphicsItems\PlotCurveItem.pyc", line 2, in <module>
File "scipy\fftpack\__init__.pyc", line 97, in <module>
File "scipy\fftpack\basic.pyc", line 12, in <module>
File "scipy\fftpack\_fftpack.pyc", line 12, in <module>
File "scipy\fftpack\_fftpack.pyc", line 10, in __load
ImportError: DLL load failed: %1 is not a valid Win32 application.
```

Comment: I'm not sure what it is exactly. All I know it's a part of scipy library.

Comment: FWIW, I've always had far more luck with [cx_freeze](http://cx-freeze.readthedocs.org/en/latest) than py2exe.

Comment: `_funcs_cxx` is part of the c-extensions that numpy/scipy uses to generalize operation application/broadcasting (stands for universal function I think).  The `fftpack` include fortran extensions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from distutils.core import setup

import py2exe

setup(console=['hello.py'])

***edit : do not include any other libraries/modules here***

NEXT at the cmd:

python hello.py py2exe

Comment: Yes, this is almost exactly what I do, but it still doesn't work. 
     
`from distutils.core import setup`     
`import py2exe`
`import numpy, pyqtgraph, scipy`
`setup(windows=['gui.py'])`

Comment: This program is quite important, because it's for my internship. Please help solve the problem.

Comment: I dont think you should import anything else at the script

Comment: Just change the file name and not anything else

Comment: Ok, I did that. Now it returns what I've just added at the end of my question.

Comment: Is py2exe win32 or win64?

Comment: It x64. Actually it's py2exe-0.6.9.winx64-py2.7.amdx64

Comment: Try reinstalling etc. or the library is corrupted or wrong format.

Comment: And the library i meant is the _ufuncs_cxx etc.

Answer (score 12):

I'm having more success with PyInstaller than Py2exe. In PyInstaller, the problem is solved by explicitly adding a reference:

```
pyinstaller myscript.py --hidden-import=scipy.special._ufuncs_cxx
```

PyInstaller also takes care of the matplotlib imbroglio, and Visual Studio DLLs.

Answer (score 1):

I got the same error message during creating .exe file using py2exe

```
File "_ufuncs.pyx", line 1, in init scipy.special._ufuncs (scipy\special\_ufuncs.c:22830)
```

It was resolved by **adding `scipy.special._ufuncs_cxx` to the `includes`** option in setup.py.
Here is what I have.

```
from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe
import numpy

setup(
    console=['hello.py'],
    options={
        'py2exe': {
            r'includes': [r'scipy.sparse.csgraph._validation',
                          r'scipy.special._ufuncs_cxx']
        }
    }
)
```

Please note that it includes some other settings to prevent numpy/scipy related errors.

- import numpy
- includes `scipy.sparse.csgraph._validation` based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14217239/870658)